# SD-WAN os to IOS-XE

Tags: router

I am trying to convert currently running SD-WAN os to IOS-XE on ISR 1100. Can anyone know how to do that? I went through some of the CISCO documentation but could not find anything effective.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can change the operation mode from `controller-mode enable` "SD-WAN" to `controller-mode disable` "IOS-XE".

`Router# controller-mode disable` - the effect is the same as write erase.

You can convert the router to `controller-mode enable` again but you'll lose all the configuration - it's recommended to create a backup first.

Best

Comment: lifer saver. Time saver, thank you

Answer (score -1):

I couldn't find a working link on the cisco forums, but I was able to find this PDF via google. Here ya go:

https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/routers/xe-sd-wan-routers/214519-how-to-downgrade-router-running-ios-xr-s.pdf